# Add new record without deleting old record Ms Access Form

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vba

Can anyone help me with MS Access Form.

I have a form in which there is a button to edit record.When that button is clicked a new form open at a specific selected record.If the record is edited/updated it should be added as new record and the old record should be there as it is.As both forms are linked with ID , so when i edit record it update in the same record which i don't want instead it should add new ID and a record for it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: "there is a button to edit record" and: "it should add new ID and a record" ... so - as you can't both stay and go - you have to make up your mind before you will be able to move further.

Comment: Is the ID field an auto-mumber type?

Comment: yes the ID is auto number @KostasK.

Comment: @Gustav,it should add new record basically with new ID that is autonumber.

Comment: thank you @KostasK. , i really appreciate your effort , you are amazing, thank you for your effort, if any else point came in your mind let me know, thank you once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution requires a new button e.g. '*Clone*' on your Edit Form.

Open the Edit Form.

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "YourFormName", acNormal, , "[ID]=" & Me!YourSubformName.Form![ID], acFormEdit, acWindowNormal
```

If you need to restrict editing the existing record, on your Edit Form's `Form_Load` event, change the recordset type to Snapshot:

```
Me.RecordsetType = 2 'Snapshot
```

When the '*Clone*' button is clicked:

```
'Create new record
With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("YourInsertQueryName")
    .Parameters("[prmID]").Value = Me![ID]
    .Execute dbFailOnError
End With

'Filter Form to the newly created record
Dim id_ as Long
    id_ = DMax("ID", "YourTableName")

With Me
    .Filter = "[ID]=" & id_
    .FilterOn = True
    'allow edits
    .RecordsetType = 0 'Dynaset
    .Requery
End With
```

---

**Insert Query:**

```
PARAMETERS [prmID] Long;
INSERT INTO tblCap ( Country, Product, [Year], PType, [Values], Notes, Source, Show, [Current],‌​ EnteredBy, Timestamp,‌​ Sector )
SELECT tblCap.Country, tblCap.Product, tblCap.[Year], tblCap.PType, tblCap.[Values], tblCap.Notes, tblCap.Source, tblCap.Show, tblCap.[Current],‌​ tblCap.EnteredBy, tblCap.Timestamp,‌​ tblCap.Sector
FROM tblCap
WHERE (((ID)=[prmID]));
```

Comment: thank you , can you please explain this bit more? thank you once again

Comment: thank you , can you let me know about "prmID" , it's referring to what ?

Comment: That is because your table contains reserved keywords. Try now.

Comment: This is the ID for the record due to be created. In simple words, if you're editing record ID=5, you need to pass that id. Do you have a subform in your form?

Comment: Yes , in the parent form their is subform , but in edit form there is no subform.

Comment: Can i have the name of the subform?

Comment: thank you so much , it started working , but it just have one problem that when the edit form open it add new record , i want that when the button is press and edit form open , in edit form there should be a button as add record, when that is press only than that new record should add , can you tell me about it.

Comment: Because your edit form is bound to a record when opens, any changes made will apply to that record. Add a button to your edit form and 1) Open the edit form, 2) create a new record (through the add button) and 3) filter the form to the newly created record. Just change the order of actions provided above and move the 'create new record' to a new button.

Comment: Changed the new button name to 'Clone' to avoid confusion. The new record is created by clicking the 'Clone' button on the Edit Form. Add a `.Requery` as shown above to show the newly created record.

Comment: So the new record is created but the Edit form is still bound to the previous record?

Comment: Can you please post your code? we won't get anywhere like this. The code to open the edit form and create the new record. Thanks

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that and that is the reason I changed the name to 'Clone'  to differentiate them as they are two separate things.

Comment: What is the Table name, 'tblCap' or 'tblCapacity'?

Comment: If you edit the record before you create a new one, it will change unless you change the recordset type to `Me.RecordsetType = 2` when the form loads. So when the Edit form loads, it's still bound to the selected record of the parent form, and any changes made will be made to the selected record.

Comment: The image tells me you edit the record first and then you create a new one. Correct?

Comment: No, you cannot do that. I've said a number of times when the form loads it's still bound to the 'old' record so any changes will be made against the 'old' record. To address this you need to change the RecordsetType to snapshot (read-only) when the form loads. This way you cannot make any changes to it and you're forced to create a new one by clicking the 'Clone button'. Once the 'Clone' button is clicked, a new record is created and the Form accepts changes.

Comment: As I said before, I replicated it here and it’s working fine. I tried to assist as much as possible but there's not much else I can do.

Comment: Recordset type is snapshot and when clone button is pressed it edit the existing record.